# Laravel Dynamic Questionnaire

Tags: php, laravel, ionic2

I have a project that uses Laravel 5.3 as the back-end  and ionic 2 for mobile application development. so When user login or registers to the app if it's first time the app will go to questions page. which it have many different questions. but the point is all questions are related to each other by user's answer. so if the first question is user's age after user chose an answer the next question is related to it completely. 
So I have two questions:

- what is the best database design for this
- how server finds out the next question depending on current question's answer given by user.

Answer (score 1):

About the 'next question', I suggest you passing -at the first load of the questions page- an object containing all of the questions and do the logic on the client side so you can save some requests to the server.

And for the DB, I think the best thing you can do is storing it in 2 tables:

```
questions
--id
--question

users_answers
--id
--user_id
--question_id
--answer
```